# Badges in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I have a few questions regarding the badges support in Nativescript:

- Push Notifications icon badges: I read in the documentation that it is available on iOS.  What about Android?  What are our options there?
- Button badges: I could not find anything on this topic in the documentation. Does anyone has any suggestions on how to implement that.
- Also, in iOS, I used the Push Browser to send a test notification and now my icon has a permanent badge number even though I had cleared the actual notification.  Is there a way to clear those?

Thank you.